# In PHP and MySQL, my code only prints one row of the table's column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm a begginer with php, and I have some troubles with it. My question is about PHP and MySQL. The purpose of the code is that I have a parameter called $sql in which I will write the SQL query. The problem is that my code only prints one row of the consult. I mean, if I have a table with 4 columns (the attributes) and in that table I have 4 rows, the code only prints one row of each column.

The method consult code:

```
public function makeConsult($sql){
    $result = mysqli_query($this->conn, $sql);
    $nrows= mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if ($nrows> 0) {
        for($i = 0;$i<count($nrows);$i++) {
            $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
            for ($j=0; $j < count($row) ; $j++) { 
                array_push($this->results, $row[$j]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "No matches found";
    }
}
```

The following method is where I print all the consults:

```
public function printResult(){
    foreach ($this->results as $key => $value) {
       echo $key . ": " . $value . "<br>";
    }
    $this->results = array();
}
```

The variable $conn is the variable where I have my sql connection.

My execution code:

```
$db = new dbConnection("localhost","root","","sportsweb");
    $db->connect();
    echo "Database name: " . $db->getDBname();
    $consult = $db->makeConsult("SELECT * FROM articles A");
    $db->printResult();
    $db->closeConnection();
```

The columns (attributes) of the table "articles" are the following ones: Id,Name,Units,BranchOffice.

Thank you! :)

Comment: Try to `return` the data inside your `makeConsult()` function.

Comment: I have done it and nothing, thank u :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two mistakes here

```
$nrows= mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($nrows> 0) {
    for($i = 0;$i<count($nrows);$i++) {
        $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM);
        for ($j=0; $j < count($row) ; $j++) { 
            array_push($this->results, $row[$j]);
        }
    }
}
```

So `$nrows` will be a count of how many rows you got back. So `count($nrows)` is useless because it's not an array

Second, I don't know where you got the idea to iterate rows like that, but you're doing it wrong. Use a `while` loop instead. I also removed the inner `for` loop and switched to a simpler `foreach`

```
$nrows= mysqli_num_rows($result);
if ($nrows> 0) {
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        foreach($row as $val) $this->results[] = $val;
    }
}
```

Comment: To me it looks like his row iteration works fine. The issue is the `count($nrows)`, as `count()` returns 1 if parameter is not an array. That said, it's confusing and `while` loops are much prettier.

Comment: Thank you very much! the Machavity answer was the good answer! now its working.

Comment: Cleaning up the inner loop was for education purposes. Not sure why you would want to iterate it like that, tho (he doesn't give us the columns from SQL)

Comment: Well, i was just staring to code in this lenguage, the `$nrows` variable was just a slip. The other things were just because i dont have so much idea how to iterate with this MySQL methods xD